# "Keinen Scanner gefunden" vs. "Kein Scanner gefunden"

Tags: accusative, nominative

Wie im Titel beschrieben geht es um den Fall "Keinen Scanner gefunden" vs. "Kein Scanner gefunden".
"Keinen" wäre (glaube ich) Akkusativ, "kein" Nominativ.
Nach dem Akkusativ kann mit "Was" und "Wen" gefragt werden, der Nominativ mit "Was" und "Wer". Für mich treffen beide irgendwie zu, leichte Tendenz zum Akkusativ.

Wie ist es nun richtig?

Comment: Ich vermute es ist die Anzeige auf einem Display. Dort könnte aufgrund von Platzgründen gekürzt worden sein. Die Akkusativ-Endung schwindet mehr und mehr (zumindest in gewissen Dialekten) und von daher ist es nachvollziehbar, an der Endung in Kurzmeldungen zu sparen. Eventuell wurde auch hier nur das Wort "wurde" ausgelassen. "Kein Scanner wurde gefunden".

Comment: Korrekt, wird auf einem iPhone / iPad angezeigt. Platz ist aber kein Problem. Im Moment steht "Keinen Scanner gefunden" aber eine in meinem Büro finden "Kein Scanner gefunden" sei korrekt(er).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Beides ist richtig.

> Kein Scanner gefunden.

ist die Kurzform von

> Es wurde kein Scanner gefunden.

Dagegen ist

> Keinen Scanner gefunden.

die Kurzform von so etwas wie

> Ich habe/Das System hat keinen Scanner gefunden.

Answer (score 4):

Als Ergänzung zur richtigen Antwort von O. R. Mapper:

Auch das wäre richtig:

> Keine Scanner gefunden.

Das ist die Kurzform sowohl von

> Es wurden keine Scanner gefunden.

als auch von

> Ich habe/Das System hat keine Scanner gefunden.

Wenn man nämlich von keinen Dingen bzw. keinem Ding spricht, kann man frei zwischen Einzahl und Mehrzahl wählen. Das ist eine Besonderheit des Indefinitpronomen *kein*. Es bedeutet im Singular dasselbe wie im Plural, nämlich die Abwesenheit des Dings (der Dinge) auf die sich dieses Wort bezieht.

Comment: Ich stimme deinen Ausführungen zu, auch wenn die Verwendung von Singular/Plural eventuell eine gewisse Erwartung impliziert, mit wie vielen Suchergebnissen denn zu rechnen gewesen wäre. Da an den meisten Arbeitsplätzen eher maximal *ein* Scanner zur Verfügung stehen sollte (bzw. das Programm auch nur einen Scanner verwenden wollen würde), halte ich die Variante mit Singular in diesem Kontext für etwas naheliegender, auch wenn der Plural ebenso korrekt wäre.